# Spring WS integration test no endpoint mapping found

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a Web service with Spring WS. I followed their guide and i set up everything fine. When i run my application and send SOAP requests to the endpoint i get the right response. (I created a SOAP client with Spring WS too). So i got that going.

Now i want to write tests. I got a unit test testing the method for the endpoint. All good and green. Right return value and such. Now i also want an integration test. This is where it goes wrong. I get the error: `WARN org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://my.app/soap/version}GetServiceVersionRequest]` (Had to censor some variables and naming for reasons. Could be they don't match. I will fix it if it occurs. In the real situation it works.)

I have the following configuration:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "serviceVersion")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema serviceVersionSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ServiceVersionPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws/version");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://my.app/soap/version");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(serviceVersionSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema serviceVersionSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/ServiceVersionRequest.xsd"));
    }
}
```

I have the following endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class GetServiceVersionEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://my.app/soap/version", localPart = "GetServiceVersionRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<GetServiceVersionResponse> getServiceVersion(@RequestPayload GetServiceVersionRequest request) {
        GetServiceVersionResponse response = new GetServiceVersionResponse();
        ServiceVersion serviceVersion = new ServiceVersion();
        serviceVersion.setMajor(1);
        serviceVersion.setMinor(0);
        serviceVersion.setRevision(0);
        serviceVersion.setBuild(1);
        response.setVersion(serviceVersion);
        return new ObjectFactory().createGetServiceVersionResponse(response);
    }

}
```

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebServiceConfig.class)
public class GetServiceVersionEndpointIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidServiceVersionRequest() throws Exception {

        JAXBElement<GetServiceVersionRequest> request = new ObjectFactory().createGetServiceVersionRequest(new GetServiceVersionRequest());

        ServiceVersion serviceVersion = new ServiceVersion();
        serviceVersion.setMajor(1);
        serviceVersion.setMinor(0);
        serviceVersion.setRevision(0);
        serviceVersion.setBuild(1);
        GetServiceVersionResponse getServiceVersionResponse = new GetServiceVersionResponse();
        getServiceVersionResponse.setVersion(serviceVersion);

        JAXBElement<GetServiceVersionResponse> response = new ObjectFactory().createGetServiceVersionResponse(getServiceVersionResponse);

        mockClient
            .sendRequest(withPayload(new JAXBSource(JAXBContext.newInstance(GetServiceVersionRequest.class), request)))
            .andExpect(payload(new JAXBSource(JAXBContext.newInstance(GetServiceVersionResponse.class), response)));

    }
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://my.app/soap/version}GetServiceVersionRequest]

    at org.springframework.ws.test.support.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient.sendRequest(MockWebServiceClient.java:184)
    at nl.app.endpoint.GetServiceVersionEndpointIntegrationTest.testValidServiceVersionRequest(GetServiceVersionEndpointIntegrationTest.java:78)
```

I also tried sending a `Source` object with a raw XML SOAP request as content. Same error. I don't know what i am doing wrong as it works when running the application. Any idea's?

Comment: I see nowhere in your configuration that the endpoint is being created or component-scanned... So I would say there is no endpoint being registered...

Comment: But then why does it work when i run the application and send requests with cURL or the SOAP client application? (Also my main `Application` class is annotated with @SpringBootApplication, doesn't this do the @ComponentScan for you?)

Comment: Because that probably has more configuration files then only `WebServiceConfig` and one of them contains a `@ComponentScan` (or maybe an xml file with `<context:component-scan />`. Nonetheless your test is only loading the Spring WS infrastructure and nothing more. No endpoint hence the error .

Comment: I annotated the Integration test with `@ComponentScan`, still nothing. I annotated the Webservice config with `@ComponentScan`, still nothing. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: No as that wouldn't solve anything... Load the other configurations as well, you are creating an integration test so I suggest loading context as you would load it normally instead of a single configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently my Spring knowledge isn't sufficient enough yet. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Will do some research.

Comment: You can try something different on your integration test. Seems to me that use MockServiceClient is not anymore the best way to make the integration test on Soap Web Service. See this example: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-producing-web-service/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/ApplicationIntegrationTests.java

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which Spring tutorial did you follow. I followed this one - https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/. Spring Boot is used and for *Test I had to change your

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebServiceConfig.class)
```

to

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) // same
@SpringBootTest
```